# Is it possible to manually put a post on a review queue?

Tags: feature-request, review

Sometimes I write a post (often an answer, but sometimes a question); but then have some doubts about whether it will be of use to the OP or the SE community.  Is it possible to manually submit your own posts to a review queue so that others can decide whether the post is useful?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Click the "submit" button, and your post will be reviewed by other users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the only flag you can raise on your own posts is "moderator attention" and you should not use that to (essentially) ask a moderator if your post is worthy.

If you feel your post should be "reviewed with the possibilities of it being removed" then you should consider carefully if it should be posted or not. But do factor in that you may just be being a little over cautious or worried about your answer being good enough.

You could try to spend a bit of time improving it, until you are confident it's pretty good. For answers as long as it's helpful, on topic, and answers the question then just post it and see what the community thinks *via voting*, rather than using the review queues. Voting on your post is still community same as review, but then you don't pester the review queues. Of course just be careful of being downvoted too much, and deleting too many posts.

All that said - maybe just have a bit more confidence in yourself? At a glance of your posts on Stack Overflow you have some good answers and questions, most are upvoted, and *none* are downvoted. When considering all posts on Stack Overflow, including all the poor or lazy ones, you are not posting poor content IMO.